# What is a simple routine in C# to convert Excel columns to integers and back again?

Tags: c#, excel, iteration

I'm trying to iterate programmatically through the columns of an Excel spreadsheet in a Microsoft Excel add-in.  It should be simple to convert from the letters to numbers (and back again to perform arithmetic on the column headers) and then iterate to the next block of alphas once I move past "Z" (or "A", if moving in the reverse), but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  Can anyone suggest a simple set of algorithms for doing this using CSharp?

Comment: The answer is NOT a "code example" it's the SOLUTION to the question.  If I'm not allowed to answer my own question (which cost me HOURS of research and is not otherwise answered on SO or anywhere else), then why is this an option in the question interface???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set of simple routines for this using basic string manipulation, division and modulus:

```
    private int DoGetIntFromColPart(string strColPart)
    {
        int nReturn = 0;

        try
        {
            strColPart = strColPart.ToLower();
            if (strColPart == "a")
                nReturn = 1;
            else if (strColPart == "b")
                nReturn = 2;
            else if (strColPart == "c")
                nReturn = 3;
            else if (strColPart == "d")
                nReturn = 4;
            else if (strColPart == "e")
                nReturn = 5;
            else if (strColPart == "f")
                nReturn = 6;
            else if (strColPart == "g")
                nReturn = 7;
            else if (strColPart == "h")
                nReturn = 8;
            else if (strColPart == "i")
                nReturn = 9;
            else if (strColPart == "j")
                nReturn = 10;
            else if (strColPart == "k")
                nReturn = 11;
            else if (strColPart == "l")
                nReturn = 12;
            else if (strColPart == "m")
                nReturn = 13;
            else if (strColPart == "n")
                nReturn = 14;
            else if (strColPart == "o")
                nReturn = 15;
            else if (strColPart == "p")
                nReturn = 16;
            else if (strColPart == "q")
                nReturn = 17;
            else if (strColPart == "r")
                nReturn = 18;
            else if (strColPart == "s")
                nReturn = 19;
            else if (strColPart == "t")
                nReturn = 20;
            else if (strColPart == "u")
                nReturn = 21;
            else if (strColPart == "v")
                nReturn = 22;
            else if (strColPart == "w")
                nReturn = 23;
            else if (strColPart == "x")
                nReturn = 24;
            else if (strColPart == "y")
                nReturn = 25;
            else if (strColPart == "z")
                nReturn = 26;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error [DoGetIntFromColPart]: " + ex);
        }

        return nReturn;
    }

    private int DoGetIntFromCol(string strCol)
    {
        int nCol = 0;
        try
        {
            int nPlace = 0;

            strCol = strCol.ToLower();
            for (int nCount = strCol.Length - 1; nCount >= 0; nCount--)
            {
                nCol += DoGetIntFromColPart(strCol.Substring(nCount, 1)) * (int)(Math.Pow(26, nPlace));
                nPlace++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error [DoGetIntFromCol]: " + ex);
        }

        return nCol;
    }

    private string DoGetColFromInt(int nCol)
    {
        string strCol = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            int nDiv = nCol;
            int nMod = 0;

            while (nDiv > 0)
            {
                nMod = (nDiv - 1) % 26;
                strCol = (char)(65 + nMod) + strCol;
                nDiv = (int)((nDiv - nMod) / 26);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error [DoGetColFromInt]: " + ex);
        }

        return strCol.ToLower();
    }
```